# 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6

Tags: postfix, dovecot, fedora, sasl

I have Postfix installed on a Fedora 38 box with the following:

```
$ grep smtp_ main.cf
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt

$ grep smtpd_ main.cf
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_auth_destination, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
# smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/arixserver.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/arixserver.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/etc/postfix/smtpd_scache
```

and I'm trying to log into it like this, where the username/password was generated with something like `perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("myvalue")`

```
$ telnet mail 25
Trying 107.133.6.164...
Connected to arix.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.arix.com ESMTP
EHLO arix.com
250-mail.arix.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 CHUNKING
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
Z=======
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Z===========YXNz
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

I've read a lot of posts here and it is my understanding that authentication against the server is handled by Dovecot (so I'm guessing the smtpd_* info is relevant) and I know the username/password are correct because I can log into the host (using SSH) using them, and also:

```
$ testsaslauthd -u $USR -p $PASS
0: OK "Success..
```

why am I getting this authentication failure?

TIA -- ekkis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generating the base64 values like this is better:

```
$ echo -ne '\000user\000password' |openssl base64
```

and the AUTH PLAIN will work